# Why does the css get corrupted when I get the data dynamically in an html?

Tags: php, css, frontend

I have a screen like this and I get this image using 3 separate divs and ul-li. The data inside are fixed data that I wrote manually.

```
<div class="cards">
    <div class="card shadow">
      <ul>
        <li class="pack">1 Points</li>
        <li id="one" class="price bottom-bar">$1</li>
        <li class="bottom-bar">1 Points</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="card active">
      <ul>
        <li class="pack">2 Points</li>
        <li id="two" class="price bottom-bar">$2</li>
        <li class="bottom-bar">2 Points</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="card shadow">
      <ul>
        <li class="pack">3 Points</li>
        <li id="two" class="price bottom-bar">$3</li>
        <li class="bottom-bar">3 Points</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[image]

There is no problem so far, but when I bring this data from the database and retrieve it with foreach, that is, when it creates the ul-li tags itself, it gets the following image.

```
<div class="cards">
    <div class="card shadow">
      <ul>
        <?php 
        foreach($package_types as $package_type){
          echo '<li class="pack">'.$package_type['package_name'].'</li>';
          echo '<li class="price bottom-bar">₺'.$package_type['amount'].'</li>';
          echo '<li class="bottom-bar">'.$package_type['package_name'].'</li>';
        }
        ?>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[image]

How can I get the image in the first photo when I get the data with Foreach?

Comment: Because you produce a different markup. You are missing the divs around each card.

Comment: So do I need to include the div tags in the foreach? @MarkusZeller

Comment: Sure, just compare the original and your output.

Comment: Well, as your manually created HTML shows, you need one div for each card don't you, so what do you think the answer to that question will be? You'll just need to have some way to decide which one from the list is tagged as active.

Comment: calm down dude you may not answer @ADyson

Comment: I'm very calm. It was just a way to get you to do some thinking for yourself, it is a good habit to get into.

Comment: yes i thought but you answer differently @ADyson

Comment: And it seemed like really you already knew the answer to your question and just needed to go and try it instead.

Comment: ok mate i remove my question thank you @ADyson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```php
<div class="cards">
    <?php
    foreach ($package_types as $package_type) { ?>
        <div class="card shadow">
            <ul>
                <?php
                echo '<li class="pack">'.$package_type['package_name'].'</li>';
                echo '<li class="price bottom-bar">₺'.$package_type['amount'].'</li>';
                echo '<li class="bottom-bar">'.$package_type['package_name'].'</li>';
                ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <? } ?>
</div>
```

You'll have to decide which one of those div tags with class `card` will also have the class `active` instead of the class `shadow`.